# How to catch custom exceptions of Futures?

Tags: java, concurrent.futures

Usually when running a `Future` and waiting for the result, I can only catch `InterruptedException | ExecutionException`.

But what if the task throws a `CustomException` that I want to catch explicit? Could I do any better than checking `e.getCause() instanceof CustomException`?

```
List<Future> futures; //run some task

for (Future future : futures) {
    try {
        future.get(); //may throw CustomException 
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof CustomException) {
            //how to catch directly?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `CustomException` is checked, it is not possible because the language does not allow you to add a `catch` for such an exception that is not part of the `Future#get()` signature, and hence can never be thrown by this method (this is part of its contract). In your code, the comment *`may throw CustomException`* is there because *you knew* the implementation of the task specific to this `Future`. As far as the `get` method of the `Future` interface is concerned, any such implementation specific exception will be  wrapped as the cause of an `ExecutionException`.

Furthermore, using `e.getCause()` *is* the correct way of inspecting such a custom exception as mentioned explicitly in the documentation of `ExecutionException`:

> Exception thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception. This exception can be inspected using the `getCause()` method.

Answer (score -1):

You could catch as many exception as you want, but it should be
in specific order where more broader exception must go after the sub-classed exception.

For example:

```
catch (CustomException e) {

} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

}

// It could be even there if CustomException is not extended from InterruptedException | ExecutionException
```

Comment: No, `future.get()` can only throw those 2 exceptions explicit. No more.